# Почему не работает вертикальное выравнивание с помощью псевдоэлемента?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
#header {
  background-color: #252323;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 60px;
}

#header:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
}

#one {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

#two {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#tree {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}

#four {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="tree"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте пожалуйста о Flexbox. Эта так сказать функция благодаря которой вам проще будет писать код, страницы автоматически становятся адаптивными и очень удобно использовать когда вам надо расположить где-то ваши элементы.

Comment: Преподаватель на курсах, почему то говорит что fkex плохо. Кому верить не знаю

Comment: Не ходите на курсы по программированию пожалуйста. Сам ходил года 2-3 назад. Запомните высококвалифицированный специалист никогда не будет за копейки преподавать "тупым" ребятам, как обычно говорят. Ему легче будет писать код и сидеть дома зарабатывая в 20 раз больше, так что уходите с курсов и ищите лучше на фрилансе опытного специалиста, как я сделал в свои годы, который за 500 рублей в час показывал и рассказывал.

Comment: Просто тупо звоните сейчас и уходите с курсов если ваш преподаватель говорит в 2017 году что flexbox это плохо, он либо неопытный либо это старая закалка, которая не привыкает с нового когда его старое уже не работает и не адаптируется. Сам ходил на курсы эти и знаю что да как, обычно студенты преподают начитавшись говна в интернете.

Comment: Вы очень категоричны. Он мне сам показывал сайты, на которых используются флексы, и там все разъезжается

Comment: И это не маленькие говно сайты, а серьезные ресурсы

Comment: https://www.onliner.by/

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/XX_qJo0xTSGqGYttPfWQNw.png

Comment: © 2001—2018  onliner.by, то чувство, когда толком ничего не поняли, этот проект не смотрю как на серьзный приглядитесь: говно дизайн, говно 2005 года блоки и просто текст. С временем поймете, что деньги выкинули зря, так что думайте как хотите и делайте что хотите:)

Comment: Всё придет с опытом:)

Comment: Ну так вопрос вполне логичный, зачем использовать технологию которую еще не до конца поддерживают все браузеры, если можно использовать ту, которая 100% будет работать везде? Когда технология флексов устаканится, тогда и вперед. Это вопрос а не утверждение

Comment: Просто потому что она новая и все?

Comment: Поверьте она уже давно устаканилась + сокращает время разработки и в придачу еще делает ваши страницы адаптивными, просто вдумайтесь, а насчет новой, я бы не сказал ибо уже время флексов заканчивается и скоро будет время cssgrid(a), так что как-то так:)

Comment: @Terletskiy Alexander на счет адаптивности не согласен. Например, bootstrap 3 - grid сетка на флоатах, и все адаптивно. А на счет использовать flex - соглашусь, но не везде. Все зависит от проекта. Например, есть фирмы которые и сейчас используют WindowsXP.(и на данный момент не собираются обновляться)

Answer (score 2):

Данный способ выравнивания по вертикали с `float` не будет работать

Вариант с `display: flex;`

```css
#header {
  background-color: #252323;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#one,
#two,
#tree,
#four {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  background-color: green;
}

#tree {
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#four {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="tree"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```